# How to use/update adaptivecards latest version features inside node-modules of react app using bot-framework webchat?

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

We developed a bot using nodejs(backend) and react webchat(frontend) via directline.In the backend we used adaptive cards with version 1.0 .....now we want to use the latest features of adaptive cards like isRequired parameter here which is not supporting in v1.0 of ac. What my problem is I am using botframework webchat v4.7.0 in which we had so many customizations inside node-modules of botframe-work. If I update this everything will gonna change my entire ui and getting unexpected behaviour and look of my bot.We tried by using v 1.3 but adaptive cards are not even rendering. Can anyone help me in reaching out this plss..it means a lot to me. Thank you.

Comment: There are a couple breaking changes from 1.0 to 1.3, maybe your cards do not render because they use tags etc not supported anymore. Can you try some up to date sample card from www.adaptivecards.io or www.madewithcards.io?

Comment: Yes, we tried but its not even rendering. I just tried one basic sample in adaptivecard.io designer with input.text as  isRequired field in 1.3v shows a warning like this.                                                                                                           [Warning] The selected Target Version (1.3) is greater than the version supported by Bot Framework WebChat (1.2). Will this impact any rendering issues??

Comment: You will have some issues but it should render the card as such. If i get you right none of your cards are rendering at all with 1.3? Do you have any error? maybe check browser console etc, the renderer usually throws errors if something goes wrong.

Comment: yes, you are right...none of my cards are rendering at all with 1.3.I'll update you with the error what I am getting soon

Comment: Adaptive Cards v1.3 is _not_ supported in Web Chat, at this time. While there are plans to update the base code of Web Chat to the most current AC package, that has not happened, yet (at the time of this writing). Because the AC package has not been updated to v1.3, this WILL block the rendering of any card passed thru that has `'version': '1.3'`.

Comment: Please try with your AC version set to '1.2'. I just tested sending a card while using v4.7.0 of Web Chat and it rendered just fine.

Comment: yes steven, its got working when I rendered using 1.2v.What if I need some features like required(mandatory) feild for input which is in AC latest version 1.3. I am unable to use this latest features right or is there any workaround for acheiving this.....

Comment: There is no workaround. AC is integrated into Web Chat which means there is no way to manually add it in. You can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/95ab4e61b1ef4de8d326dcdefa98911efbcff7ac/packages/bundle/package.json#L36) that WC uses v1.2.3. There is an open issue requesting AC be updated to v1.3 [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3487). It's _tentatively_ scheduled for the next release (4.12.0). Show your support by giving it a thumbs up or leaving a comment. More interest will mean more consideration of development.

Comment: @steven Got it wat u said. Thanks for your suggestions.